# What is theory behind AWGN channel command matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, probability, telecommunication

Kindly tell me the theory behind the two commands (marked with `***`) of an AWGN channel in the below shown code.

Code:

```
N_all = [10^3*ones(1,6) 10^3*ones(1,5)];
Eb_no = [0:2:20];
for ii=1:length(Eb_no)
     N = N_all(ii);
     b = (1/sqrt(2))*rand(1,N)>0.5;
     ip = qpsk_new(b);
     s = ip;
***  noise = 1/sqrt(2) * [randn(1,N/2)+j*randn(1,N/2)];
***  y = s+10^(-Eb_no(ii)/20)*noise;
end
```

Comment: Worthy to have a look: http://se.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/awgn-channel.html#a1071501088

Answer (score 3):

The [`randn`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) function in the first marked line generates complex, **Gaussian**-distributed (1), **independent** (2)  samples with zero mean and unit variance. The second marked line scales those samples according to the specified signal-to-noise ratio ([*E*<sub>B</sub>/*N*<sub>0</sub>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eb/N0)) and **adds** (3) them to the signal.

These operations stem from the definition of AWGN:

1. The "G" in "AWGN" means "**Gaussian**".
2. The "W" means "white". The term "white" applied to a stochastic process [means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) that the samples are statistically **independent** (or uncorrelated; but in the Gaussian case they are equivalent conditions).
3. The "A" is "**additive**", so you add the noise to the signal.